# Vector Field Problem

Tags: vector-spaces

Why does $\frac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{ r^2} = \frac{\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{ r^3}$?

I've never seen this before and I'm not sure what I should consult to understand this situation.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\hat{r}$?

Comment: It would be the unit vector in the radial direction.

Comment: So $\hat{\mathbf r} = \frac{\vec{\mathbf r}}r$, where $r = \sqrt{\vec{\mathbf r} \cdot \vec{\mathbf r}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit vector in the radial direction, $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, is given by
$$
\mathbf{\hat{r}} = \frac{\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{|\mathbf{\vec{r}}|} = \frac{\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{ r},
$$
where $|\mathbf{\vec{r}}|$ denotes the length of $\mathbf{\vec{r}}$, which is $r$.